# Using commerce module for online payment for just 4 product/services?

Tags: commerce

I starting a website which is offering 4 Apartaments to rent. The visitor will be able to make online payments. My question: Should I use the  Drupal Commerce module for this ?

Will I be able to treat each Apartment as a product? I need to include a map and a calendar for each one. Can I accomplish this with the commerce module.

There is no much documentation about this module and it seems complicated....

Comment: Have you seen http://drupal.org/project/rooms ? (Drupal Rooms is a booking and room management solution for hotels, vacation rentals and B&Bs.)

Comment: It seems a good module but I don´t want the entire site depends in just one module with no stable version yet.

Comment: The Rooms module, even though in dev, is really stable. Instead of trying to duct tape something together, I would suggest using it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you'd do was display the rooms and manage their bookings, then I would say 
Commerce was not only excessive, but perhaps even entirely wrong.

However, since you mention online payments, I think it could be a good fit, for managing of those. No other contrib module is likely to have as many "out of the box" solutions for payment today, or developed tomorrow.